# Error while writing adapters in ember js

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
 namespace :'http://localhost:8078/advanceSpring/service/getReverse.action',
        suffix: '.action',

      pathForType: function(type) {
        return this._super(type) + this.get('suffix');
      }

});
```

// Getting error while executing code . "Error is unexpected token"

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like where does this exception occur?

I've tried pasting your adapter code into my own adapter and I get an error while parsing JSON, but that's because I don't have a backend at that address and my backend returns a 404 HTML page which naturally doesn't parse as JSON.

Comment: @PedroRio can u please give your email id .

Comment: I think it's more interesting to have the discussion here on stackoverflow, so that others can benefit from it. In any case, how can I pass you my email (without posting it here?)

Comment: @PedroRio  I'm trying to configure ember and Spring . but i'm getting and error can you pls help or can you provide steps how to connect . I'm doing with starter kit

Comment: HTML: <script type="text/x-handlebars" id ="honey"> 
<form {{ action 'handleSubmit' on="submit"}}>
  {{input value= name}}
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
 </form>
  </script>

Comment: "https://gist.github.com/gilesbowkett/5367666 " use this link . i have written my code there in comment box under name of honeyjn15 . please help if you can

Comment: I'm not familiar with working with ember in globals mode, I've always used ember-cli but I don't see anything specifically wrong with your code.

Can you create a JSBin that reproduces the problem, or an EmberTwiddle, or a github repo with the part of the app that causes the error? I would guess on some integration error, but looking at this I can't figure it out.

Have you tried setting up a server that returns dummy data to see if the problem comes from there? Do you have a stack trace of the problem when it occurs?